# Listpicker with button inside choice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listpicker

I am a student and currently doing a project on window phone. Basicly, I am create a library apps. The problem is, when I use listpicker, as a choice for the room I want to browse, using an intergrate button for each choice. I want each button lead me to a diffenrent portrait pages.  For example, when I press button on "room 101" choice, it lead me to "page 101", and if "room 102" is chosen, the "page 102" is opened.
Here is my C# code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

    namespace Library
{
public partial class location : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class SampleData
    {   
        public string Floor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Room
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
    public location()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<SampleData> dataSource = new List<SampleData>();
        dataSource.Add(new SampleData() { Floor = "First",Room = "101" });
        dataSource.Add(new SampleData() { Floor = "First",Room = "102" });
        dataSource.Add(new SampleData() { Floor = "First", Room = "103" });
       this.listPicker.ItemsSource = dataSource;
    }

          private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleData data = (sender as Button).DataContext as SampleData;
        ListPickerItem pressedItem =
        this.listPicker.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as ListPickerItem;
           if (pressedItem != null )
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Room.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Is there a question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: I mean how can I specify each button command inside each choice to open different specific page.

Answer (score 0):

once you have SelectedItem or SelectedIndex based on SelectionChanged event, you can navigate to appropriate page.

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont quite sure that I understand your answer. Can you be a little more detailed ?

Comment: use the SelectionChanged event and have a look at SelectedItem or SelectedIndex that gives you the item user clicked

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not quite clear I assume that you know how to get the item pressed and your problem is how to navigate to the correct page only.

In the click handler do the following

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SampleData data = (sender as Button).DataContext as SampleData;
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Room.xaml?roomId=" + data.Room.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In the OnNavigatedTo handler for your Room page you then can do:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        int roomId = (int)NavigationContext.QueryString["roomId"];

        if(roomId == 101)
        {
            //Modify page content for room 101
        }
        else if(roomId == 102)
        {
            //Modify page content for room 102
        }
        //...
    }
```

If you really want to navigate to a completely different page you only have to modify the Navigation Uri

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Room{0}.xaml", data.Room), UriKind.Relative)
```

**Note**: But normally you just want to adapt the content of the page according to the data passed to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your expaination. Makes my day.